# working example of multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I am looking for a working example of multiprocessing.Queue after being pointed to it from this question: [Python utilizing multiple processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838738/python-utilizing-multiple-processors)

I came across [this](http://jeetworks.org/node/81), but it only seems to use one of my 12 processors even when I change `num_processes=12`. I also changed `num_jobs = 200000` so that it wouldn't complete so fast.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with that example or point me to one that works?

Comment: It seems like that was just a bad example where it took longer to put together the list of work to do than it actually took to do the work.

I put together something else with a nearly identical Worker class and got it to utilize all processors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are examples [in the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Do these examples work? If not, it may be that the problem itself is not Python, but something else instead.