# Multi-processing and Queue

Tags: python, python-multithreading

After some lookup into google and posts of stackoverflow and other sites, i'm still confused on how i can apply a queue and threading on my code:

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import re
# for threading and queue
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
# for threading and queue
import time
from datetime import datetime

class Database_connection():
    def db_call(self,query,dbHost,dbName,dbUser,dbPass):
        try:
            con = None
            con = psycopg2.connect(host=dbHost,database=dbName,
                                   user=dbUser,password=dbPass)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(query)
            data = cur.fetchall()
            resultList = []
            for data_out in data:
                resultList.append(data_out)
            return resultList
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
                print 'Error %s' % e
                sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            if con:
                con.close()

w = Database_connection()
sql = "select stars from galaxy"

startTime = datetime.now()
for result in  w.db_call(sql, "x", "x", "x", "x"):
    print result[0]
print "Runtime: " + str(datetime.now()-startTime)
```

lets supose the result will be 100+ values. How can i, put those 100+ results on queue and  execute ( print, for example ) then 5 at time  using queue and multiprocessing module?

Comment: does your question have to do anything with DB, maybe you can simplify   the example

Comment: Hi,
yes, it have , because i need to loop over the results.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal i just edited the final lines with your sugestion.

Comment: it is not a db question right? so you should change those psycopg2 call, replace it with a function call may be with a sleep, so that atleast people can run the code as it is

Comment: So you want to analyze the results of the SQL response in 5 different threads?

Comment: @nater Exact. for example, the result are ftp addresses, and i want to upload files at same time, instead one by one. 

Dont know why this question is getting vote down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the following:

```
def worker():
    w = Database_connection()
    sql = "select stars from galaxy"
    for result in  w.db_call(sql, "x", "x", "x", "x"):
        if result:
            jobs = []
            startTime = datetime.now()
            for i in range(1):
               p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
               jobs.append(p)
               p.start()
            print "Runtime: " + str(datetime.now()-startTime)
```

I belive it is not the best way to do it, but for now solved my problem :)

Comment: This still only starts one process that does all of your work.

Comment: Why the `for i in range(1)`? If you want to parallelize then use `multiprocessing.cpu_count` (and eventually other data) to use a "good number" of processes.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge on python, that was the way i found to iterate just one time over the sql result. What sugestion you give tu replace it? =)

Comment: Does that even run? It looks like each pass through should launch a new process giving you infinite recursion.

Comment: @tcaswell, Dont know why it was voted down. In fact it works pretty well ( im using it now ).

Maybe this is not the most smart solution, but it solved my problem  using  my limited knowledge on Python/development.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want this code to do?

You get no output from this code because `get()` returns the next item from the queue ([doc](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get)).  You are putting the letters from the sql response into the queue one letter at a time.  the `i` in `for i...` is looping over the list returned by `w.db_call`.  Those items are (I assume) strings, which you are then iterating over and adding one at a time to the `queue`.  The next thing you do is to remove the element you just added to the queue from the queue, which leaves the queue unchanged over each pass through the loop.  If you put a `print` statement in the loop it prints out the letter it just got from the queue.

`Queue`s are used to pass information between processes.  I think you are trying to set-up a producer/consumer pattern where you have one process add things to the queue and multiple other processes which consume things from the queue.  See [working example of multiprocessing.Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082391/working-example-of-multiprocessing-queue) and links contained there in ([example](http://jeetworks.org/node/81), [main documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)).

Probably the simplest way to get this working, as long as you don't need it to run in an interactive shell, is to use `Pool` (lifted almost verbatim from [the documentation of `multiprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html))

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5) # sets the number of worker threads you want
def f(res):
    # put what ever you want to do with each of the query results in here
    return res
result_lst = w.db_call(sql, "x", "x", "x", "x")
proced_results = p.map(f, result_lst)
```

which apply what ever you want to do to each result (written into the function `f`) and returns the results of that manipulation as a list.  The number of sub-processes to use is set by the argument to `Pool`.

Comment: Im not sure if the construction is write, but seens o be not, i will read what you have sugested and update the question propertly. thanks.

Comment: i edied the question with a more simplified example. to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion...

```
import Queue
from threading import Thread


class Database_connection:
    def db_call(self,query,dbHost,dbName,dbUser,dbPass):
        # your code here
        return

# in this example each thread will execute this function
def processFtpAddrMt(queue):
    # loop will continue until queue containing FTP addresses is empty
    while True:
        # get an ftp address, a exception will be called when the
        # queue is empty and the loop will break
        try: ftp_addr = queue.get()
        except: break

        # put code to process the ftp address here

        # let queue know this task is done
        queue.task_done() 


w = Database_connection() 
sql = "select stars from galaxy"
ftp_addresses = w.db_call(sql, "x", "x", "x", "x")

# put each result of the SQL call in a Queue class
ftp_addr_queue = Queue.Queue()
for addr in ftp_addresses:
    ftp_addr_queue.put(addr)

# create five threads where each one will run analyzeFtpResult
# pass the queue to the analyzeFtpResult function
for x in range(0,5):
    t = Thread(target=processFtpAddrMt,args=(ftp_addr_queue,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

# blocks further execution of the script until all queue items have been processed
ftp_addr_queue.join()
```

It uses the Queue class to store your SQL results and then the Thread class to process the queue.  Five thread classes are created and each one uses a processFtpAddrMt function which take ftp addresses from the queue until the queue is empty.  All you have to do is add the code for processing the ftp address.  Hope this helps.